# Manipulating the Header of the Same Page Based on the User Status

Tags: php, html, database

I have a problem regarding my page's logged in status on the header. I actually made it work but I used two htmls to do so. I was wondering if I could do that in just one html to prevent the redundancy of pages just for the header. Below are the codes I've used, a mixture of php and html. Though when I run it it seems to be working, but it's not getting the $userRow value when it runs, just a "Hi!". Also, I cant seem to execute the else function of the second php. Whenever the user signs out, it just redirects me to the login form.

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header("Location: login.php");
}
else {
    $_SESSION['user'] = true;
}

$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
?>

<body>
<div id = "header">
<ul>

<?php
if ($_SESSION['user'] == true) {
        //I want the below codes to only be seen when the user has successfully logged in.
    echo '<div style = "float: right"><li><a href = "profile.php">' . "Hi!" . $userRow['user_name'] . '</a>' . '<a href="logout.php?logout">' . "Sign Out" . '</a></li></div>';
} else {
        //I want this code to be seen when the user has not logged in yet. Making this like the default set up of the home page when the user hasn't logged in yet.
    echo '<div style = "float: right"><li><a href="http://localhost/reg2/login.php">' . "Login" . '</a></li></div>' ;
    echo '<div style = "float: right"><li><a href="http://localhost/reg2/signup.php">' . "Sign Up" . '</a></li></div>' ;
}
?>


</ul>
</div>
```

Here's a picture of what it results to when I login https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKSKP.png

Here's what I want it to be like when I haven't login yet :https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPq0D.png
As I said, the second output doesn't show, whenever I sign out it only redirects me to the login page, which is completely another php file.

EDIT: (Got it fixed, working code below. Thanks for the answers that made this happen. :D)

```
<body>
<div id = "header">
<ul>
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    echo '<div style = "float: right"><li><a href="http://localhost/reg2/login.php">' . "Login" . '</a></li></div>' ;
    echo '<div style = "float: right"><li><a href="http://localhost/reg2/signup.php">' . "Sign Up" . '</a></li></div>' ;
}
else {

    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
    $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
    echo '<div style = "float: right"><li><a href = "profile.php">' . "Hi!" . $userRow['user_name'] . '</a>' . '<a href="logout.php?logout">' . "Sign Out" . '</a></li></div>';
}

?>




</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Then you shouldn't do the `header('Location ...`?

Comment: ....Of course. Well, it's kinda working now with the header. The only problem now is the Hi! $userRow['user_name'], still won't show

Comment: You should create an answer instead of edtting the question with the answer and self-accept it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    $_SESSION['user'] = false;
}
else {
    $_SESSION['user'] = true;
}
```

Comment: yes, I made it like this : 
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    echo '<div style = "float: right"><li><a href="http://localhost/reg2/login.php">' . "Login" . '</a></li></div>' ;
 echo '<div style = "float: right"><li><a href="http://localhost/reg2/signup.php">' . "Sign Up" . '</a></li></div>' ;
}
else {
    $_SESSION['user'] = true;
 $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
 $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
}

Comment: I see the codes are all scrambled... basically if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) I changed it to the login and signup output. Then if it's the else statement, it'll get the name of the user and execute the logged in status.